# sencha touch keeps content and overlays it

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

i have got problems:
http://www.burning-emotions.at/shop/
1234567 user
pwd 1234567

When changing between the tabs, sometimes it keeps the content and overlays it,...is this a bug of sencha touch or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: looks ok here testing with safari. How do you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yep, looks fine on Safari, sucks on Firefox. Can't test on a mobile device. Can you be more precise when it happens _sometimes_? Is it random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are tapping on the next tab in that handler hide the previous panel by using `hide()` function and `show()` the required panel